# How can I calculate dates from another column and another table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

table 1:

```
|| *handtool_id* || *maintenance_interval_value* || *unit_unit_id* || *handtool_last_date_of_maintenance* || *handtool_next_date_of_maintenance* ||
||             1 ||                            1 ||              5 ||                          2014-11-07 ||                                     ||
||             2 ||                            1 ||              6 ||                          2014-11-07 ||                                     ||
||             3 ||                            4 ||              4 ||                          2014-11-07 ||                                     ||
```

table 2:

```
|| *unit_id* || *unit_name* || *unit_value* || *unit_parent_id* ||
||         1 ||      Minute ||            1 ||                1 ||
||         2 ||        Hour ||           60 ||                1 ||
||         3 ||         Day ||         1440 ||                1 ||
||         4 ||        Week ||        10080 ||                1 ||
||         5 ||       Month ||        32767 ||                1 ||
||         6 ||        Year ||       525949 ||                1 ||
```

What is the right syntax for calculating the `*handtool_next_date_of_maintenance*` from  `*maintenance_interval_value*` and from `*unit_unit_id* + *handtool_last_date_of_maintenance*`?
Thank you

Comment: You need to join the two tables and compute it from there, but I wonder why you have a separate table with the units. These are not going to change, so why not enter the maintenance interval in, say days? It would make the computations significantly simpler.

Comment: nothing yet.. i need storing the units in separated table because i using that table for another reasons too

Comment: i try calculate the next day with table join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mats Kindani suggested, you need to join the two tables to get the next maintenance date.

```
SELECT
table1.handtool_id,
table1.handtool_last_date_of_maintenance,
DATE_ADD(table1.handtool_last_date_of_maintenance, 
    INTERVAL table1.maintenance_interval_value*table2.unit_value SECOND) next_date_of_maintenance
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.unit_unit_id = table2.unit_id
```

The function I'm using to calculate the next maintenance date is called [DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp). You can read up on its usage in previous link.

Finally, if you want to populate `table1` with the "next date of maintenance", you'll have to transform my select query into an update query.